# Dynamic populating the drop down list based on the button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a small project where I am trying to change the drop down list option based on the button that is clicked. 
Its sort of like populating the list based on the value of the first list that I is listed here https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php
However currently I have my select list displayed using php and html. I make a call to my table in the  tags above my page and then display the information.

```
<?php

        $selList = array();
        $query= $dbh->query("SELECT * from CarsShop order by dtDroppedOff");
        foreach ( $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
            $selList [] = array('carID'=> $row['carID'], 'vin'=> $row['CarVIN']);
        }
?>
<select  name="carLst"  id="carLst"  onClick="retrieveCarInfo(this.getSelected().getProperty('value'));" size="5" >
                <option>List of cars...</option>
                <?php foreach ($selList as $entry) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $entry['carID']; ?>"><?php echo $entry['vin']; ?></option>
                    <?php }?>
</select>
```

However I want to add two buttons..one to display all cars that are ready for pickup and those who are not. I have a simple 1 or 0 in my table and I can pull information like that. However how could I toggle back and forth when clicking the buttons. My select list would have to populate each time i click the corresponding button.

Now I am aware I can make a JSON call as an onclick() and request this information and assign it on the onSuccess callback, but is there any way of doing this like how I already have it?

Comment: Search for it so many examples online.

Comment: Do it with JS/CSS - hide options in second select e.g. onChange first select or with AJAX onChange -> load list from SQL.

Comment: Several ways to go about it: 1) print two different selects and use js to toggle; 2) print each option with a class of available or unavailable. Use js to toggle visibility of each class

Comment: I looked for examples and they all mentioned using ajax, which I didn't want to do simply because I am already ,making a lot of request calls on my form. But @RafałKonarski and Tim Morton you both have been super helpful. I forgot I could toggle the information. Thanks!